# Make rectangles from agricultural field sizes (ArcGIS 10)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, agriculture, rectangle

I got a task to do as research assistant of which im not sure how to do..

I have a layer with field polygons of agricultural fields (pretty large scale).

I want to create rectangles for each field by using the field size information. The rectangles have to have a define width (each field the same width), so the size of the rectangle is only up to the length for the respective field and they have to be adjacent to each other. I hope it can be automated this far, that if the basis layer information (field size) changes also the rectangulars change.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, GIS SE is not a primary research facility where you state what you want to do and options are offered (Google already does that). Instead, we're the place to go after you've started one of those options, but it isn't working as expected.  In order to assist you, we need to know exactly what you have determined is necessary, what you have accomplished so far, and what exactly  has gone wrong.

Comment: There is no simple task to create rectangles in arcgis.I think You should use python scripting and develope custom tool

Comment: Calculate coordinates of output rectangle corners using distance field.Create point feature class using the coordinates. Convert point fc to polygon : http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012380